# Can't access the React files on the git page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an issue with react page host:

1. when I host my portfolio it only give error 404 saying file not found it doesn't disappear until I edit the URL manually and choose the index.html path (.../main/index.html)
2. after I edit the URL the react component doesn't work only html element is displayed if I open console

I get error ca't import outside module which means it wants me to delete the:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM, { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
```

if I try to use npm host the portfolio works fine here is the the link to check it [portfolio repo](https://github.com/sifeashraf/SifeAshraf-portaflio)
[protfolio website](https://sifeashraf.github.io/SifeAshraf-portaflio/)
if it didn't work add this to the link (.../main/index.html)

I tried using the `<script>` to link the react index.js to index.html but it didn't help at all

Comment: I'm not trying to fix your problem, but it you are going to import a module via a [script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), you'll need to tell the browser that it's not regular JS: `<script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>`